# Executing multiple shell scripts on multiple remote servers at the same time using a java program

Tags: java, shell, jsch

I have a requirement where I need to execute multiple shell scripts on multiple servers at the same time and display the results of these scripts on a page. The number of shell scripts and number of servers will depend on user selection. So the number of shell scripts, servers and hence the number connections that I have to make can rise to even 30-40 at some point in time. I read some previous answers where it was suggested to use JSch API for remote execution of scripts, but with these many number of connections, I doubt JSch is the best way to go about it. 
Do you think JSch is still the best approach for this scenario?
Or there some other ways which are more suitable for this kind of situation?

Comment: Why do you doubt jsch?

Comment: Because of the number of connections that my program is going to make. My application is user-interactive, so the response time is a major concern.

Comment: There's hardly any other commonly available interface for executing scripts on a server than the SSH.

Comment: @JakeTyler you would have the same problem if you use plain-old `ssh` client? Besides that, if you do networking, please take into account slow connections, dropping connections, and handle these in a user friendly way.